# Search list of strings in txt file via excel

Tags: excel, text, vba

I have many txt files in my folder. I have also have a list of their names in column 1, i need to search separate 1 string in each files which are listed in column 2. If such txt is found then it should say "Found" or else not found.

i was trying to modify below code based on my requirement but i unable to do it as its giving me the error for which i don't know the solution.

```
Sub SearchTextFile()

Dim FName, SName As String

Raise = 2

Do While Raise <> ""
FName = Cells(Raise, 1)
SName = Cells(Raise, 2)

Const strFileName = "Y:\New folder\" & FName & ".txt"
Const strSearch = SName

Dim strLine As String
Dim f As Integer
Dim lngLine As Long
Dim blnFound As Boolean

f = FreeFile

Open strFileName For Input As #f
Do While Not EOF(f)
    lngLine = lngLine + 1
    Line Input #f, strLine
    If InStr(1, strLine, strSearch, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
        Cells(Raise, 3).Value = "Found"
        blnFound = True
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
Close #f
If Not blnFound Then
    Cells(Raise, 3).Value = "Not Found"
End If

Raise = Raise + 1

Loop
```

End Sub

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: The error is "Constant expression required"

Comment: You are missing a `Loop` after `Raise = Raise +1`

Comment: @Rosh which line?

Comment: this 2 lines: {Const strFileName = "Y:\New folder\" & FName & ".txt"
Const strSearch = SName
}

Comment: Easiest fix would be to use a normal varible instead of a const.

Comment: Constant values must be calculable at *compile time* , but FName isn't known until *run time*, hence the error message.  Use a constant for the folder path, and build the full path using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this modification

```
Sub Search_Text_Files()
Dim b           As Boolean
Dim sName       As String
Dim sSrch       As String
Dim strFile     As String
Dim sLine       As String
Dim f           As Integer
Dim r           As Long
Dim l           As Long

r = 2

Do While Cells(r, 1) <> ""
    sName = Cells(r, 1)
    sSrch = Cells(r, 2)

    strFile = "Y:\New folder\" & sName & ".txt"
    b = False
    f = FreeFile
    Open strFile For Input As #f

    Do While Not EOF(f)
        l = l + 1
        Line Input #f, sLine
        If InStr(1, sLine, sSrch, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
            Cells(r, 3).Value = "Found"
            b = True: Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    Close #f
    If Not b Then Cells(r, 3).Value = "Not Found"
    r = r + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Bro thanks you so much... i have accepted the answer working fine on my test data :)